# Are Palestinians and Negev Bedouin a single ethnic/national group?

Tags: israel, palestine, nationalism

Are [Palestinians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palestinians) and [Negev Bedouin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negev_Bedouin) a single ethnic/national group? (In other words: are all of them simply Palestinians?)

Is the difference between them simply the traditional lifestyle (Palestinians being settled - like farmers or city-dwellers, while the Bedouins are nomadic) or do they have different ethnic origin? Yet another option - perhaps they have diverged on the subject of the Arab nationalism and Palestinian identity (the Negev Bedouins generally recognize the State of Israel and even serve in the army - unlike the majority of the Israeli Palestinian citizens. However, the matter is further complicated by the existence of the [Palestinian Bedouin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palestinian_Bedouin), apparently distinct from the Negev Bedouin.)

(I have the same question about the [Israeli Druze](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Druze_in_Israel).)

Comment: A single ethnic group according to whom? If you don't specify, I fear this will suffer the "Are Mormons Christian?" problem (or even the "Are Catholics Christian?" problem).

Comment: @origimbo no offense, but this seems like a generic reaction to the title. The body of the question explains more specifically what I try to understand - if you want that I improve it, please be more specific.

Comment: I'm starting from the viewpoint that ethnicity is a social construct (it's possible you're using the word differently), and as such you will (almost) always find people who will separate a group into sub-groups based on differing traditions, or unify them (often by contrasting to yet another group). As a concrete example, Cornish is recognised as minority ethnicity in the UK and EU, but you'll also find the existence of pan-Celtic nationalist groups who claim a larger single ethnicity.

Comment: @origimbo My interest is from the point of view of the emergence of the Arab nationalism: why don't Bedouins identify with the Palestinian struggle for the national self-determination?

Comment: Well do they identify as separate? would be a start.  Something to consider is Bedouin relations with Palestinian residents pre-1920s or so - it is not unusual for a new arrival group to coopt one set of residents against another.

Comment: Are Palestinian Muslims and Palestinian Christians a single ethnic group, or two separate but related groups? There isn't a firm dividing line (aside perhaps from self-identification but that tends to vary a lot even within families).

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica *it is not unusual for a new arrival group to coopt one set of residents against another* - this is what I am trying to understand, if one of them is a more recent arrival or they differ only by lifestyle or they diverged on the question of national independence (vs. loyalty to tribe/clan).

Comment: @StuartF are Jews and Muslims in Palestine a single ethnic group or two separate but related groups?

Comment: @RogerV. if you wish to understand why the Bedouins don't support establishing a Palestinian state, then you need to first establish that that is the case and then ask about *that*. Currently your question is not about politics at all.

Comment: @political_noob Bedouin and Druze certainly seem less militant than "Palestinians"... even those who have Israeli citizenship. But the question has broader political implications - e.g., if they are not the same ethnic/national group, then who are the real indigenous population of Palestine?

Comment: "Ethnic origin" in many definitions of ethnicity includes the lifestyle.  The idea that ethnicity is tied to bloodlines is fairly isolated to cultures where bloodlines could be tracked and where the mixing of ethnicities faced social or legal boundaries; at least for enough generations to create a cohesive genetic pool.  Without a better definition, this is an unclear question.

Comment: This is a matter for the anthropologists, not a matter of governments and policies.

Comment: I feel like asking who the "real" indigenous population of Palestine is kind of misunderstands the issue of indigeneity in a fairly harmful way.  Indigenous people are people who live on a piece of colonized land when colonizers show up to displace them.  It's only really a useful term in this context.  People move around.  There is no plot of dirt that has been held by the same people since humanity started humaning.  No one has a fundamental metaphysical claim to some piece of land as inherently "theirs".  But when you have lived somewhere for centuries and someone who isn't from there

Comment: rolls through and takes over, then you need a term to differentiate the people doing the taking from the people getting taken from.

Answer (score 1):

In short:

- Bedouins are the ancient desert-dwelling "Arab", originating from the Arabian peninsula. Outside of the arabian peninsula, Bedouin tribes are living in Jordan, Israel's south and Egypt's Sinai Desert. Bedouins are certainly an ethnic group, almost never intermarrying with outsiders and preserving their anciant lifestyle.

In Bedouin culture the whole idea of land ownership (not tribal bounderies) is quite fragile, let alone political rule, etc. Bedouins pledge allegaince to family and tribe.

- Druze(s) are an Islamic sect, originating from Egypt, currently living in northern Israel and southern Syria (after escaping persecution in Egypt). Druze don't accept converts and almost never marry members of other groups, so by now they can probably be considered an ethnic group.

According to Druze doctrine, one must be loyal to the ruling gevernment.

Will add sources shortly.